# Javascript to get data from Weather Underground "history" API

Tags: javascript, api, weather

I have problems to get data from Weather Underground from a historical day (**same script works fine for my current observations**). Example for yesterday:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

heute=new Date(); 
jahr=heute.getFullYear(); 
monat=heute.getMonth()+1; 
tag = heute.getDate()-1;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/ea1cb0c0f1995212/history_'+jahr+monat+tag+'/q/pws:INORDRHE156.json",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  success : function(parsed_json) {


 var minhumidity = parsed_json.history.dailysummary[0].minhumidity; 
 var day = parsed_json.history.dailysummary[0].date.pretty;
 document.getElementById("z8").innerHTML = minhumidity;
 document.getElementById("z9").innerHTML = date; 

  }
  });
});
</script>
```

So "**day**" works for me, output is: **November 13, 2017**

But "**minhumidity**" should bei '**90**' (or some other value), but there will be just a **blank**.

I get both values (**day** and **minhumidity**) at the same way, where is the Problem?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You should use the dev tools to get a look at the json returned from the API and post that here.

Comment: It was my first post, so pls forgive me ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your url `"http://api.wunderground.com/api/ea1cb0c0f1995212/history_'+jahr+monat+tag+'/q/pws:INORDRHE156.json"` change it to (note that i changed ' with "):

```
<script>

heute=new Date(); 
jahr=heute.getFullYear(); 
monat=heute.getMonth()+1; 
tag = heute.getDate()-1;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/ea1cb0c0f1995212/history_"+jahr+monat+tag+"/q/pws:INORDRHE156.json",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  success : function(parsed_json) {


 var minhumidity = parsed_json.history.dailysummary[0].minhumidity; 
 var day = parsed_json.history.dailysummary[0].date.pretty;
 document.getElementById("z8").innerHTML = minhumidity;
 document.getElementById("z9").innerHTML = date; 

  }
  });
});
</script>
```

And please add var, let, const whatever to your variables. For example:

```
var heute = new Date(); 
var jahr = heute.getFullYear(); 
var monat = heute.getMonth()+1; 
var tag = heute.getDate()-1;
```